# WP7 Deserialize JSON

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, serialization

I'm new to c# and  having problems with the below giving InvalidCastException on the line `Addresses address = (Addresses)serializer.ReadObject(e.Result);`:

```
namespace My_App
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Addresses
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "line1")]
        public string line1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "line2")]
        public string line2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "postcode")]
        public string rpostcode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "city")]
        public string city
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember(Name = "state")]
        public string state
        {
            get;
            set;
        }    
    }


    public partial class sim : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public sim()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
                 var webClient = new WebClient();

                    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;

                    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.myurl" UriKind.Absolute));

        } 

    }

    private void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Addresses));
            Addresses address = (Addresses)serializer.ReadObject(e.Result);

    }

}
}
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "@type": "accountAddress",
        "line1": " 1",
        "line2": "NORWICH ROAD",
        "postcode": "NR1 1AU",
        "city": "NORWICH",
        "state": "NORFOLK"
    },
    {
        "@type": "accountAddress",
        "line1": " 2",
        "line2": "NORWICH ROAD",
        "postcode": "NR1 1AU",
        "city": "NORWICH",
        "state": "NORFOLK"
    },
    {
        "@type": "accountAddress",
        "line1": " 3",
        "line2": "NORWICH ROAD",
        "postcode": "NR1 1AU",
        "city": "NORWICH",
        "state": "NORFOLK"
    }
]
```

I need this to be in a suitable format to use in a listpicker object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is, your JSON has a set of addresses and you are just trying to access only one Address. In other words, your serializer returns a List of Addresses but you are trying to convert it to a single Addresses object.

So change your code to something like this,

```
List<Addresses> addressList = (List<Addresses>)serializer.ReadObject(e.Result);
```

And eventually what you need is a list or a collection to bind it to the ListPicker.

Comment: Thanks, it's still throwing the InvalidCastException error on that line.  I think I've tracked it to -`'(e.Result).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' {"Timeouts are not supported on this stream."}` but not sure how to fix this

Comment: I think you have to change the initialization of the serializer also to a list!

Comment: got it thanks! - changed line to read `var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Addresses>));` and it now parses correctly.
What would be the best way to get this array into the listpicker in the format 
`addressList.line1 addressList.line2 addressList.city addressList.state addressList.rpostcode`

Comment: Simple if you know about DataBinding: `listPicker.ItemsSource = addressList;` and if you don't know DataBinding check this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/07/25/windows-phone-7-binding-data-to-listbox-through-code.aspx)

Comment: well don't know if this is the best solution, but I came up with:  
`List<string> myaddresses = new List<string>();
            for (i = 0; i < addressList.Count; i++)
                 {
                     myaddresses.Add (addressList[i].line1 + " " + addressList[i].line2 + " " + addressList[i].city + " " + addressList[i].state + " " + addressList[i].rpostcode);
                 }
            listPicker.ItemsSource = myaddresses;`

Comment: In that case each line of address is an individual item, and will cause problems if you want to access, `listPicker.SelectedItem`. Go through [this blog](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth) to know more about list picker data binding.